# How to add PushNotification to a Laravel queue?

Tags: php, laravel-4, queue

I have an automatic iOS push notification set up on my Laravel Forge server. However, sometimes not all push notifications get sent out. So, I'm trying to solve this by adding them to a queue. This is the code I have in place right now:

```
$devices = DB::table('devices')->get();

foreach ($devices as $device)
{
    $push = PushNotification::app('Development')
                ->to($device->device)
                ->send($message);

     $push = PushNotification::app('Distribution')
                ->to($device->device)
                ->send($message);
}
```

Now, I tried doing it this way:

```
$this->dispatch($push = PushNotification::app('Distribution')
                ->to($device->device)
                ->send($message));
```

But that - obviously - doesn't work. How do I do this properly? I have to admit that I don't quite understand the syntax of adding to the queue and it doesn't help that the documentation is not that clear in this area.

Comment: did you find out how to do this?